# Is it incorrect to say "If you could"?

Tags: can-could

I tend to use the following construction often in my e-mails:

> It would be great if you could...

However my German colleague repeatedly reminds me that according to the [rules](http://www.lernen-mit-spass.ch/lernhilfe/wiki/doku.php?id=conditional_clauses_if-saetze_bedingungssaetze) he was taught, using "if" together with "could" in the way I do is strictly speaking incorrect. I am however certain that this construction is quite common (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/64793/49654)) and can often convey *willingness* rather than *ability*.

Is the above construction strictly speaking incorrect, and is there a better replacement for it?

Comment: Related: [May you please explain this?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/118576/43980)

Comment: Remember that “if he could” is the same as “if he were able”. Since there is nothing wrong with “If he were able to finish today, that would be good”, there is similarly nothing wrong with your formulation. There **is** a common German blunder of using *would* in both halves of a conditional in English, but this is not it.

Comment: I think your colleague is assuming that *would* and *could* work the same way in English. They don't. Maybe this is because 
*würde* and *könnte* work the same way in German. (I don't remember enough of my German to decide whether this is true.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with "**If ... could ...**".

(I looked at your linked rule, but can't comment on it as my German is not good enough.)
What I would say is that *sometimes* "rules" are given to learners as *guidelines* to prevent them making elementary mistakes until they have mastered more of a language.  That is what I suspect happened in the related question I mentioned in a comment above: [May you please explain this?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/118579/43980).

***Could*** is the *past tense* and *subjunctive form* of the verb ***can***, which may be [defined](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=can&title=21st) as follows:

> **can *verb*** (*past tense **could***)
>   1. to be able to • *Can you lift that?*
>   2. to know how to • *He can play the guitar*.
>   3. to feel able to; to feel it right to • **How can you believe that?**
>   4. used to express surprise • *Can it really be that late?*
>   5. used to express a possibility • *The weather can change so quickly in the mountains.*
>   6. to have permission to • *Can I take an apple?*
>   7. used when asking for help, etc • *Can you give me the time?*

Taking selected meanings from above, there is nothing wrong with

> If you can/could ...

for example

> If you are/were able to ...
>   If you know how to ...
>   If you feel able to ...

Comment: What’s a “subjective” form, and how does it differ from an “objective” form? Usually discussion of the nominative and the accusative is limited to substantives and their modifiers, not to verbal forms.

Comment: @tchrist I assume that TrevorD means *subjunctive* rather than *subjective* (although this is still a bit of an over-simplification).

Comment: @PElliott Thanks. I *did* mean "subjunctive" - and I was trying to 'keep it simple'!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is correct; you can read this article which has an example of

> if you could

Example 1

> Even if you could get a zero percent home loan for 30 years, if it eats up more than half your net pay, you probably can't afford it.

Example 2

> What if you could capture the entire history of recorded human existence into one epic infographic for the ages?

References

[reference for example 1](http://www.heraldnet.com/article/20130813/BIZ/708139993)

[reference for example 2](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2013/08/all-hail-histomap-4000-years-of-history-in-a-single-poster/)